# Registration Form - Prefix as radio buttons in Magento

Tags: php, forms, magento, registration

How I can change the default PrefixOptions in Radio Buttons. the default code is in the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml and the prefix code is:

```
<?php if ($this->showPrefix()): ?>
    <div class="field name-prefix">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>"<?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <?php if ($this->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
            <?php else: ?>
                <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>" class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
                <?php foreach ($this->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_option?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getPrefix()==$_option):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option)?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the base layout is a bad idea as any changes will be gone after the next Magento update.
You first need to copy this file to your own theme, i. e. `app/design/frontend/default/[your theme]/template/customer/widget/name.phtml`.

Afterwards you could change this code to the following:

```php
<?php if ($this->showPrefix()): ?>
    <div class="field name-prefix">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>"<?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <?php if ($this->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
            <?php else: ?>
                <!--<select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>" class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>-->
                <?php foreach ($this->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                    <?php if(empty($_option)) continue; ?>
                    <!--<option value="<?php echo $_option?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getPrefix()==$_option):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option)?></option>-->
                    <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $_option?>" <?php if ($this->getObject()->getSuffix()==$_option):?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>"/> <?php echo $this->__($_option)?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <!--</select>-->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I just commented the old lines (select element) that you do not need anymore but left it in for reference.

Comment: Hi is perfect thank you so much, can you take a look here maybe you have any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104635/disable-second-dropdown-if-the-first-is-not-selected

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the post as answer. I'll have a lool ar your other problem then.