# Disable 3th, 4th dropdown list if 1st or 2nr are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this issue: In my form there are 4 dropdownlist and when the  1st (category1) or 2nd (software1) dropdown list is selected, the 3th (category2) and 4th (software2) must be disabled.

For this issue I find this script at [disable-second-dropdown-if-the-first-is-not-selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104635/disable-second-dropdown-if-the-first-is-not-selected) but I do not trust to modify this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
category1
<select name='cat1'>
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>little</option>
  <option value='2'>good</option>
</select>

software1
<select name='soft1'>
  <option value=''>Select one</option>
  <option value='W'>Word</option>
  <option value='E'>Excel</option>
  <option value='PP'>Power Point</option>
</select>

<br />
category2
<select name='cat2'>
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>little</option>
  <option value='2'>good</option>
</select>

software2
<select name='soft2'>
  <option value=''>Select one</option>
  <option value='W'>Word</option>
  <option value='E'>Excel</option>
  <option value='PP'>Power Point</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var setEnabled = function(e) {
  var name = this.name.replace(/1/, '2'); //get name for second drop down
  $('select[name=' + name + ']')
      .prop('disabled', 0 === this.selectedIndex) // disable if selected option is first one
};

$(function() {
  $('select[name=cat1], select[name=soft1]')
      .on('change', setEnabled)
      .trigger('change'); // trigger on page load
});
</script>
```

How to modify this?

Thanks

Comment: are the 3rd and 4th drop downs on the bottom or on the right? the ones on the bottom are disabled

Comment: Do you also want to set them to "Select one" when you disable them?

Comment: @ depperm: I have edit the post

Comment: @Steven Moseley: no, when dropdownlist is disabled, set them clean

Comment: @Frankie - I gave you an answer below, but your requirements are a little ambiguous.  Did you want BOTH disabled when EITHER is selected?  The logic in your code looks like you want to test cat1 against cat2 and soft1 against soft2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main thing you want is to flip `===` for `!==`

However, to get this working on a matrix, where both top inputs trigger enabling/disabling of both bottom inputs, you'll need to test both on change of either.

```js
var setEnabled = function(e) {
  var selected = $('select[name=cat1]').prop('selectedIndex') > 0 || $('select[name=soft1]').prop('selectedIndex') > 0;
  $('select[name=cat2], select[name=soft2]').prop('disabled', selected); // disable if selected option is first one
  if (selected) {
    $('select[name=cat2], select[name=soft2]').prop('selectedIndex', 0)
  }
};

$(function() {
  $('select[name=cat1], select[name=soft1]')
      .on('change', setEnabled)
      .trigger('change'); // trigger on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
category1
<select name='cat1'>
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>little</option>
  <option value='2'>good</option>
</select>

software1
<select name='soft1'>
  <option value=''>Select one</option>
  <option value='W'>Word</option>
  <option value='E'>Excel</option>
  <option value='PP'>Power Point</option>
</select>

<br />
category2
<select name='cat2'>
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>little</option>
  <option value='2'>good</option>
</select>

software2
<select name='soft2'>
  <option value=''>Select one</option>
  <option value='W'>Word</option>
  <option value='E'>Excel</option>
  <option value='PP'>Power Point</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok we're almost there. When category1 is selected, category2 and software2 must be disabled and clean.

Comment: @Frankie - added the cleaning code.  Now will do the double-test

Comment: @Frankie - There was a bug while I was editing to your requirements, which I fixed.  Try again?

Comment: you are the best! Work fine!